# Error in fetching hibernate session in a quartz job

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I am getting the below exception when I tried to get the current session in a repository. Please suggest a work around for fixing this error. I am using Spring 4.2.5, Quartz 2.2.1 and hibernate 4.2.21

> 22:53:00,034 ERROR [org.quartz.core.JobRunShell]
>
> > (org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-1)
> >     Job DEFAULT.manualUploadFileProcessingJob threw an unhandled
> >     Exception: :
> >     org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobMethodInvocationFailedException:
> >     Invocation of method 'runTrigger' on target class [class
> >     com.honeywell.zing.web.manualupload.utils.triggers.ManualUploadFileProcessingHandler]
> >     failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException:
> >     org.hibernate.HibernateException: **Could not obtain
> >     transaction-synchronized Session for current thread**   at
> >     org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:266)
> >     [spring-context-support-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]    at
> >     org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:75)
> >     [spring-context-support-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]    at
> >     org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
> >     [quartz-2.2.1.jar:]     at
> >     org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
> >     [quartz-2.2.1.jar:] Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException:
> >     org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain
> >     transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Quartz Scheduler

```
<bean id="manualUploadFileProcessingHandler" class="com.honeywell.zing.web.manualupload.utils.triggers.ManualUploadFileProcessingHandler">  
        <property name="soapUploadFileManager" ref="soapUploadFileManager"></property>


    </bean>

    <bean id="manualUploadFileProcessingJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="manualUploadFileProcessingHandler" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="runTrigger" />
        <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
    </bean>
 <!--   Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.-->
    <bean id="manualUploadFileProcessingTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="manualUploadFileProcessingJob" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 * * * * ?" /><!-- Every day Every hr Every min the trigger runs 0 * * * * ? -->
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetails">
            <list>
                <ref bean="manualUploadFileProcessingJob" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="manualUploadFileProcessingTrigger" />
                <!-- <ref bean="expiryTrigger" /> <ref bean="WorkplansSyncTrigger"/> 
                    <ref bean="RefreshConnectionPoolsTrigger" /> <ref bean="sampleExpiryTrigger" 
                    /> <ref bean="unsentSampleDataToCAMPTrigger" /> <ref bean="unsentEmailLogsTrigger" 
                    /> -->
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Hibernate:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SoapUploadFileDaoImpl extends ZingHibernateDAO implements SoapUploadFileDao {


@Override
    public List<RawFileRecord> getAllUnProcessedFiles() {
        Session session = null;

        try {
            log.logInfo("ZING_MAN_INFO","getAllUnProcessedFiles","Fetching all unprocessed files for manual upload");
            session = currentSession();
            Query query = session.createQuery("from RawFileRecord rawFileRecord where rawFileRecord.processingStaus=:processingStatus");
            query.setParameter("processingStatus", UNPROCESSED_PROCESSINGSTATUS);
            return query.list();

        } catch (HibernateException he) {
            log.logError("ZING_MAN_INFO", "getAllUnProcessedFiles", "Error fetching unprocessed files ", he);
            throw new HibernateException(he);
        } catch(Exception ex){
            log.logError("ZING_MAN_INFO", "getAllUnProcessedFiles", "Error fetching unprocessed files ", ex);
        } finally {

            //releaseSession(session);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```